# Is there a way to identify a Tri-Rate Copper SFP in a Juniper MX device

Tags: juniper, sfp, hardware

Juniper has two kinds of Copper SFPs. One (**SFP-1GE-T**) only does Gigabit. The other one (**SFP-1GE-FE-E-T**) can also run at 100M and 10M respectively.

The problem is, in the chassis inventory *both* are identified as **SFP-T**:

```
FPC 11           REV 10   750-038489   XXXXXXXX          MPCE Type 1 3D
  CPU            REV 04   711-038484   XXXXXXXX          MPCE PMB 2G 
  MIC 0          REV 27   750-028392   XXXXXXXX          3D 20x 1GE(LAN) SFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           10x 1GE(LAN) SFP
      Xcvr 0     REV 02   740-013111   XXXXXXX           SFP-T
      Xcvr 1     SX       740-011782   XXXXXXX           SFP-SX
      Xcvr 2     SX       740-011782   XXXXXXX           SFP-SX
      Xcvr 3     LX       740-011783   XXXXXXX           SFP-LX10
      Xcvr 4     REV 02   740-013111   XXXXXXX           SFP-T
      Xcvr 5     REV 02   740-013111   XXXXXXX           SFP-T
      Xcvr 6     REV 02   740-013111   XXXXXXX           SFP-T
      Xcvr 7     REV 02   740-013111   XXXXXXX           SFP-T
```

On insert we see the SFP type in the syslog:

```
fpc11 MIC(11/0): Link 7 Tri Rate Copper SFP  - plugged in.
```

but except for that I know no way to distinguish these two. And after two years these logs are probably gone and noone knows the type anymore. So, is there another way?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Post for reference for others: The only way I know of is to log onto pfe.

### MX80 Example

`start shell pfe network tfeb0`
`show sfp x`

#### Amongst Output

```
SFP Type:            1000BASE-T Copper SFP
```

vs

```
SFP Type:            Tri Rate Copper SFP
```

sfp index are populated on insertion order -- `show sfp list` to work out your index.

Answer (score 1):

This part number is only 1GE `740-038291`

This part number is 10/100/1000 `740-013111`

Answer (score 0):

Try the command '`show chassis pic fpc-slot slot-number pic-slot slot-number`':

This is the [`show chassis pic` command reference](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.1/topics/reference/command-summary/show-chassis-pic.html)

Comment: I don't know what the output would be when using original optics, but for our vendor (which flashes the optics so that they appear as tri-rate SFPs) it's not helpful:

```9    GIGE 1000T        n/a   FLEXOPTIX          T.C12.02.A        n/a      0.0```